# Setting double to a limitated value, exclusive

Tags: java

I have a double value in one of my classes, with has an upper bound.

The problem is when I try to set this variable to a value with is greater then its limit. When that happen I would like to set it to the closest value inside the limits.

And an awkward situation happens when I try 
 `.getLimit() - Double.MIN_VALUE`

Which has no effect.

Can anyone clarify this for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Double.MIN_VALUE` is so small that it will be lost due to precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Java 8, the [`Math.nextDown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextDown-double-) function appears to be exactly what you're looking for.

If you can't use Java 8, the relevant line from the source of `Math.nextDown` is:

```
return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) +
                                           ((d > 0.0d)?-1L:+1L));
```

You can simplify this a bit if you know `d` is positive.

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. I did not wanted to define a constant by myself.. it would not make since since I was looking to use Double for precision.

Comment: Tested and working in Java 8...thanks, I will accept in a min.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `Math.ulp()`:

```
  double d = 1.234566789123456789e20;
  double delta = d - Math.ulp( d );
  System.out.println( d > delta );
```

Prints `true`.